# Why is my php page still caching after taking the appropriate measures?

Tags: php, api

I have a PHP page which fetches prices from an API and I'd like it to not cache anything as I've set the page to reload every 15 seconds `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15">`so the prices can be updated.

I've added the following code to my index.php file, but it still seems to cache, when I open up Google Chrome in incognito mode, (sometimes) I see different numbers.

In`<body>` I have:

```
<?php
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Last-Modified: $ts");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
?>
```

Also:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

I'm also using this: `<html manifest="manifest.appcache">`at the start of my code, which contains the following:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# Cache manifest version 1.0

# no cache

NETWORK:
*
```

BTW, isn't the first block of PHP code doing exactly what the second block of PHP code is doing? Is it necessary to have them both? Also, isn't the purpose of the manifest.appcache defeated when I try to do with php?

Comment: do you know were it is being cached?

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your issue, but I would put all your `header()` calls before you send your `<head>`.

Comment: have you considered that the API provider could be caching responses (keyed on api key), in order to prevent greedy database usage ?

Comment: But it is an api from an exchange that provides prices of a crypto, I don't think they'll cache that on purpose

Comment: @MrGlass I will try to put everything before <header> and see if it makes any difference, I'll let you know this afternoon, thanks for your quick replies btw!

Comment: BTW, isn't the first block of PHP code doing exactly what the second block of PHP code is doing? Is it necessary to have them both? Also, isn't the purpose of the manifest.appcache defeated when I try it to do with php?

Comment: Implement a good old run-of-the-mill cachebuster, and be done with it …?

Comment: No idea what that is x) But @Mr Glass I think it works fine now it is in between the <head> tags! Thanks for the tip <3 I deleted manifest.appcache and the first block of PHP code and only use the second part btw :) By the way, how to mark a reply as the correct answer?